# Woocommerce default emails design not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have enabled all emails from admin end woocommerce, but when I submit order the design of the email is not working I mean it's not showing the original default woocommerce emails design it's showing something like paragraphs I have tried to customizations but nothing happens. please guide me where I am making mistakes the email screenshot given below:

[image]

Even where from its coming, I have tried to find but no solution gets. I have tried emails customizations, templetes plugins as well nothing going to work. Also, my woocommerce plugin is the latest as well. Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: Find here  wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails

Comment: this one i have already tried its not working for emails \\

Comment: Then It might be override in the theme or similar functionality plugins